# Obtener la ruta de un archivo al cual al darle doble click inicia el programa .exe creado en python

Tags: python, rutas

Buenas y gracias a toda esta maravillosa comunidad.

Estoy aprendiendo a programar con python, he creado una pequeña aplicación la cual lee un archivo de texto con una extensión específica. Este programa lo hice ejecutable para Windows con pyinstaller, los archivos de texto los he asociado a la aplicación en cuestión para que se inicie la aplicación al abrir uno de estos archivos. Lo que estoy intentando averiguar es como obtener la ruta del **archivo** al iniciarse el programa cuando doy doble click en el **archivo** de la extensión de este programa.
No he encontrado nada sobre este tema. Gracias!

Disculpad mi ignorancia y estoy trabajando en ello.

Comment: Si entendí bien, lo que quieres es que al darle doble click a un archivo con una extensión especifica (por ejemplo .xxx) te lo abra con tu nuevo programa hecho en python. entonces en windows, puedes ir al explorador de archivos, buscar un archivo con la extension xxx, le das click derecho -> Abrir con..., en esa pantalla buscas tu programa y seleccionas "Usar siempre esta aplicacion para abrir los archivos .xxx". Pero hay que tener en cuenta que si tu programa se ejecutara desde la linea de comandos debería poder recibir el nombre del archivo en el primer parametro. Ej: `tuapp.exe file.xxx`.

Comment: No, eso ya lo tengo hecho, es que al darle doble click al archivo .xxx al iniciar el programa obtenga la ruta de es archivo en cuestión y no tener que abrir un filedialog para indicar al programa la ruta del archivo

Comment: Entonces debes mirar como pasar parametros por consola a tu aplicacion hecha en python (Yo no sé python entonces no te puedo ayudar ahi), lo que si sé, es que la ruta del archivo al que le das doble click se le pasa como primer parámetro a tu aplicación (como si fuera llamado por consola como te indique anteriormente)

Comment: Muchas gracias, con tu repuesta ya tengo por donde empezar